# Mule Batch Max Failures not working

Tags: mule

I'm using mule batch flow to process the files. As per the requirement I should stop processing the batch step for further processing after 10 failures.
So I've configured `max-failed-records="10"` but still I see around 99 failures in my logger that is kept in complete phase. The file which the app recieves will have around 8657 rows. so loaded records will be 8657 records.

**Logger in complete phase:**

```
 <logger message="#['Failed Records'+payload.failedRecords]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

**Below image is my flow:**
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any logs related to max failure limit reached?

Comment: yes I'm seeing the logs saying limit reached so adding to failures, but I see this message after few records are tried and OnComplete I see payload.failureRecords as 99 records. which should be 10 right??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its default behavior of the mule. As per [Batch Documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/batch-processing#basic-anatomy) Mule loads 1600 records at once (16 threads x 100 records per block). Though max failure is set 10 it will process all loaded records, but it wont load next record blocks as max failure limit is reached.

Hope this helps.